# How to extend a widget in october

Tags: octobercms

I want to extend the lists widget to add the double click functionality.

My best approach right now it's to find a way to override the `/modules/backend/widgets/lists/partials/_list_body_row.htm` to add a call to a new additional method in that partial, since thanks to the cool feature of extensions I can already add dynamically methods and properties with

```
Lists::extend(function($lists){
 // add dynamic method and property
});
```

That way I'll be able to add the logic and change the lists partials to call that new logic the same way the one click way works.

Another approach would be (that would require changing the core of octoberCMS) adding a new alias called "List" (for example) and change all the calls to makeWidget from `Backend\Widgets\Lists` to the defined alias (for instance, the ListController behavior in the makeList method), but of course that would require change vendor code and that would be veeeery wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you able to find any solution for that ???

Comment: Nop, sorry, also I have changed jobs since then, so right now I can't remember almost anything about OctoberCms :(